# From the system of equations prove $a+b+c=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots

> $a,b,c$ are distinct real numbers and $x,y$ are also real numbers. we have these equations:
>
> $${ \begin{cases}{a^3+ax+y=0} \\ {b^3+bx+y=0} \\
>  {c^3+cx+y=0}\end{cases} }$$ Prove $a+b+c=0$

I added all the equations together and get:

$$a^3+b^3+c^3+(a+b+c)x+3y=0$$

It is similar to Euler identity (because we have $a^3+b^3+c^3$). if $a+b+c=0$ then from Euler identity we can conclude $a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$. and equation change to:

$$3abc+3y=0$$
But it seems that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $a,b,c$ are the roots of cubic $$p(t)=t^3+tx+y$$

> so by vieta $a+b+c=0$

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? This solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you please explain how you find $p(t)$? I can't realize it.

Comment: @Soheil well, all the equations $a^3+ax+y=0,b^3+bx+y.=0..$ all hint to the fact that  $p(t)=t^3+xt+y$

Comment: @JoshuaWang thanks fro supporting me,maybe the downvoter felt that my answer was too 'obvious' and I should have left it as a comment

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore to me it was not obvious at all!

Comment: For more detail, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore, Not sure who has down-voted it & why! Just wondering, in this approach we don't need $$a\ne b\ne c$$  right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee We do. $a,b,c$ distinct ensures that these are the distinct roots of $t^3+tx+y=0$ so that $a+b+c=0$ holds by Vieta. If this is not ensured, then $a,b,c$ might not describe the set of all roots of the cubic and vieta fails. Albus should add this to their answer.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri thanks for explaining that .........

Answer (score 2):

Subtract consecutive equations to get$$a^3-b^3+(a-b)x=0\iff a^2+b^2+ab+x=0~~\because a\ne b\\b^3-c^3+(b-c)x=0\iff b^2+c^2+bc+x=0~~\because b\ne c$$
Subtract these equations to get$$a^2-c^2+b(a-c)=0\iff a+b+c=0~~\because a\ne c$$

Comment: Alternatively, we can solve any two simultaneous equations for $x,y$ and replace those values in the third

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution to Albus Dumbledore's. Note that the three equations imply that the nonzero vector $(1,x,y)$ is in the kernel of
$$\begin{pmatrix}a^3&a&1\\b^3&b&1\\c^3&c&1\end{pmatrix}$$
of determinant (after factoring)
$$(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(a+b+c).$$
But also, the determinant must be 0 since it has nontrivial kernel. So $(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(a+b+c)=0$ and by the assumption that $a,b,c$ are distinct, the result follows.